# In angular apply selected class to a star on the basis of value coming from backend

Tags: angular

This is what I have tried so far.

HTML

```
<div class="rating-area text-center">
     <p>Average Rating:</p>
     <div class="rating-count">{{selectedValue } }</div>
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
             <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars" style="display: inline-block">
                 <li class="cursor-pointer" [ngClass]="{'selected': (selectedValue)}">
                     <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                 </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
stars: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
selectedValue: 3;
```

I want to apply **selected** class only to three stars if **selectValue** specified in .ts file is 3.
How can we do that? Can someone provide their input?

Comment: `[ngClass]="{'selected': star <= selectedValue}">` ?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Tried this. But it does not apply "selected" class to them.

Comment: Maybe share a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': (selectedValue)}"
```

Try this:

```
[class.selected]="star === selectedValue"
```

This will give the element the class "selected" when the current star has the same value as the selected value.

Comment: When I use this and if I give selectedValue = 3, so only third star gets the selected value. 
What should have been done is 3 stars must have been selected.

Comment: change the attribute to [class.selected]="star <= selectedValue"